# SET related P&C question with certain condition

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

This is a Korean CSAT question that I have translated.

The set $X = \left\{ {x \mid x \le 10,x \in N } \right\}$.  Find the number of functions $f:X \to X$ that satisfy:

(A) For all natural numbers $x$ below “$9$”, $f\left( x \right) \le f\left( {x + 1} \right)$

(B) When  $1 \le x \le 5$,$f\left( x \right) \le x$; When $6 \le x \le 10$ ,
$f\left( x \right) \ge x$

(c) $f\left( 6 \right) = f\left( 5 \right) + 6$

My approach is as follows:

Using the cases of condition B we get the following table

[image]

There are 4 cases outlined in shaded colors in the picture:

Case 1: $f(5)=1, f(6)=7$

Case 2: $f(5)=2, f(6)=8$

Case 3: $f(5)=3, f(6)=9$

Case 4: $f(5)=4, f(6)=10$

How do we proceed from here?